# Eclipse Language Servers: There is '1' error in 'javaee_7.xsd' on faces-config.xml

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I'm trying to build a JSF project, starting from Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse 2021-06.
Tried with WildFily (tried with versions 22, 23 and 24)... No way!
Tried to make a 2.2 and 2.3 JSF project... no way.
I always receive an error in the faces-config.xml file.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to make the same project in Eclipse 2020-12 and had no problem ! Everything works!

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advace.

Comment: Is this error message actually stopping you from proceeding?

Comment: Yes. It crashes when i run every kind of project. Even if almost empty.

Comment: Eclipse crashes?